# AssemblyDependencyResolver not resolving

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I'm trying to create a custom `AssemblyLoadContext` utilizing an `AssemblyDependencyResolver` in C# under Net Core 3.1 (Visual Studio 2019).

But while I can see `AssemblyDependencyResolver` as a public sealed class in the Object Browser, neither IntelliSense nor the source code editor will admit it exists (and I have a `using System.Runtime.Loader` statement in the file so it should be recognized).

I've never seen something like this. How do I go about creating an instance of `AssemblyDependencyResolver`?

Comment: I made a brand new ConsoleApp targeting netcoreapp3.1 using VS 2019, and was able to get IntelliSense to see `AssemblyDependencyResolver` just fine (also with `using System.Runtime.Loader`).  I guess it's time to challenge assumptions: is your project truly targeting .NET Core 3.1?  Could it be targeting something else, say netstandard2.1?  Have you turned it off and back on again?  :P

Comment: Right you are -- the project targets NetStandard2.1, which AssemblyLoadContext supports. But AssemblyDependencyResolver only targets Net Core 3 and 3.1. I was confused by an example in the Microsoft docs. Thanx! If you'll write it up as an answer I'll be happy to accept it and upvote it.

Comment: No problem - glad it could help, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment in the question:

Targeting netstandard2.1 will not allow you to access the `System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyDependencyResolver` class; only targeting netcoreapp3.0 or netcoreapp3.1 will do that.